# Why is the method of undetermined coefficients not working

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$y'' + w^2 y = \cos{(wt)}$
I'm supposing that it has a solution of the type $y = A \cos{(wt)} + B\sin{(wt)}$ but I'm getting this:

$y'' + w^2 y = \cos{(wt)} = (-A w^2\cos{(wt)} - B w^2\sin{(wt)}) + w^2(A \cos{(wt)} + B\sin{(wt)}) = 0$

So I can't compare the coefficients because the expression is zero. What is the problem here?

Yet I can't solve by variation of parameters because I'm getting too much complicated expressions.

Comment: It's generally a good idea to solve the homogeneous equation **first**. You will find that the general solution of the homogeneous equation $y''+w^2y=0$ is $y=A\cos(wt)+B\sin(wt)$ which shows you that $y=A\cos(wt)+B\sin(wt)$ can't possibly be a solution of the nonhomogeneous equation $y''+w^2y=\cos(wt)$. So you have to try something else for your particular solution, namely, $y=At\cos(wt)+Bt\sin(wt)$.

Comment: @bof Can you explain me why is $y=At \cos{(wt)}+Bt\sin{(wt)}$ the right form to choose? Thank you!

Comment: That form could be derived using something called the [annihilator method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilator_method). When I took elementary differential equations, I just learned a simple rule of thumb: If the form you want to use doesn't work (because it's a solution of the corresponding homogeneous equation), multiply it by the independent variable, $t$ in this case. Repeat as needed. It's related to the fact that you get a factor of $t$ in the solution of a homogeneous linear DE when the characteristic equation has a repeated root.

Comment: You could just compute the general solution for a right side $\cos(w_1t)$ where $w_1\ne w$ and then in that solution take the limit $w_1\to w$. Which will essentially turn out to be a derivative for $w$. And $\frac{d}{dw}\cos(wt)=-t\sin(wt)$ etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frequency of the inhomogenous term matches the natural frequency of the differential operator, so you need additional terms of the form $C t\cos(wt) + Dt\sin(wt)$.